# How to concatenate name of variables in Cpp?

Tags: c++

I have class Walls in my program. Inside of class are objects Wall1, Wall2 etc.
I want to do something like this:
class definition:

```
class Walls {
    
public:
    Walls(){
        nPositionX = nMapWidth - 1;
        nHoleSize = 1;
        nHolePosition = rand()%(nMapHeight - nHoleSize);
        count++;
    }
    static int getCount() {
        return count;
    }
    int getPositionX()
    {
        return nPositionX;
    }
    
    
private:
    int nPositionX;
    int nHolePosition;
    int nHoleSize;
    static int count;
};
```

access to object

```
for (int i = 0; i < Walls::getCount(); i++) {
    
    int nPosx = Wall"i".getPositionX();
    
}
}
```

Is that possible in c++?
Ok big thanks for everyone for help. I don't know why I didn't tried it before.

Comment: You can't. Learn about arrays.

Comment: No, but you can use `std::vector` to maintain a collection.

Comment: Or a `std::map` using name strings as keys, ie: `std::map<std::string, Wall> walls; ... int nPosx = walls["Wall" + std::to_string(i)].getPositionX();`

Comment: Show us the definition of `Walls`.

Comment: @user253751 and cigien ok ;/ thank U

Comment: @RemyLebeau this should be global, yes?

Comment: @KonradStolarz No, it should be a member of your `Walls` class

Comment: @RemyLebeau ok, thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use an array or `std::vector` for that, eg:

```cpp
std::array<Wall, MAX_WALLS> m_walls;
or
std::vector<Wall> m_walls;

...

// initialize m_walls[0], m_walls[1], etc as needed...

...

for (size_t i = 0; i < m_walls.size(); i++) {
    int nPosx = m_walls[i].getPositionX();
    ...
}
```

Or, you can use a `std::map`, eg:

```cpp
std::map<std::string, Wall> m_walls;

...

// initialize m_walls["Wall1"], m_walls["Wall2"], etc as needed...

...

for (int i = 1; i <= getCount(); i++) {
    int nPosx = m_walls["Wall" + std::to_string(i)].getPositionX();
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The code is not executed until you execute your program, but in the executable there are no variable names anymore. Hence, no.

You can use an array or [vector](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector):

```
struct Wall { int get_position() const { return 42; } };
using Walls = std::vector<Wall>;

Walls walls;
for (const auto& wall : walls) {
    int nPosx = wall.get_position();
}
```

Or if you really want to map names to objects, use a [`std::map`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/map):

```
std::map<std::string,Wall> named_walls;

named_walls["stone wall"] = Wall();
```